# Tools suitable for semi-automatic video labeling?

Tags: deep-learning, labels, image-segmentation

So far I have been using *labelme* to label objects in videos I use for training, but it is quite time consuming.

Are there good tools to help with that?

I was thinking about a tool where I label some frames, and the tool would then match the labelled areas in the next frames. Note that a simple interpolation would not be enough.

Comment: I have heard good things about https://github.com/microsoft/VoTT

Comment: Can you provide more details about the labeling ? Do you need bounding-boxes, pixelwise labeling,..?

Answer (score 0):

You could use some tracking lib. Adrian Rosebrock gives nice overview on his [blog](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/07/30/opencv-object-tracking/).